# How to replace an expression in several TeX files?

Tags: strings

Can I replace all instances of one string expressions in the `TeX` files in one directory?

For example, let's say I want to replace all `\frac` with `\myfrac` in more than one file simultaneously.

Comment: Alternatively, you could let the files keep using the original `\frac{}{}` and use `\let\OldFrac\frac`, and `\let\frac\myfrac`. And if `\myfrac` was originally using `frac`, replace the occurrence of `frac` with `OldFrac` within the definition of `\myfrac`.

Comment: This looks very borderline for on-topic, as it's about editors/text manipulation rather than TeX. @PeterGrill's approach is TeX-based, but it's not clear that the question is rally about that method at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which operating system are you using? If you're using a *nix based operating system (Mac included), it's probably easiest to do this out of TeX, in the command line / terminal:

```
find /home/my/directory -type f -exec sed -i 's/OldString/NewString/g' {} \;
```

(using a combination of `find` and `sed`.)

So you'd need:

```
find /home/my/directory -type f -exec sed -i 's/frac/myfrac/g' {} \;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. As remark for others, at first it didn't work and I had to add the two symbols "" after -i as suggested [here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=95246).

Comment: Assume that only applies to Mac users?

Comment: Mac Version 10.5.8 here, I don't know how far this reaches.

Comment: Why not just `sed 's/something/else/g' *.tex`? Shell-agnosticism?

Answer (score 1):

Most advanced text editors have a `replace` feature that can apply to a whole set of files at once.

For example, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) on Windows provides this feature. As mentionned in another response to this question, if you are using a *nix-based system, you could quite easily use the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Vim, you can try the following: First open one of your .tex files in vim.

Load the other .tex files from the same directory by opening them in hidden buffers:

```
:args *.tex
```

Now all the *.tex files in the directory  are loaded into (hidden) buffers. You can apply a standard substitution command to each of these files by issuing the following command:

```
:argdo %s/string1/string2/g | update
```

The **%** is the range (entire file), **s** denotes the substitution command, **string1** is found and replaced by **string2** on each line, and **g** indicates that this is done globally (so not just the first instance on each line). The last part **| update** will automatically save all the files after the substitution is complete.

Because the backslash is a "special" character, you need to escape it with another backslash. In your case, you would issue the command:

```
:argdo %s/\\frac/\\myfrac/g | update
```